# I want to change excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

My cell looks like this `3s4446V6PK1HVGT`, I want to change it to look like this, `PK1HVGT` after the formula is done.

The pretext is different for all cells but the outcome will be 7 characters long after the formula starting with The PK in the data input.

I was looking for a formula to do this but could not find one can somebody help please ?

Comment: You need to provide more info. Is pretext same for all cells or is it a single cell you are trying to change?

Comment: Are there any criteria for changing the cell contents?  Is it always the right 7 letters you want?

Comment: The pretext is different for all cells but the outcome will be 7 characters long after the formula starting with The PK in the data input.

Comment: yes the right 7

Comment: THX everybody awesome help...

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in cell `A1` then your formula in `B1` must be:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("PK",A1,1)+1)
```

This formula works no matter how many characters you need to extract from the cell.

It will extract all the characters to the right of the first *PK* it finds including the *PK* string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the last 7 characters, then just use:

`=RIGHT(A1,7)`